# How to create a product page with fully custom CMS content?

Tags: cms

I would like a product detail page that doesn't follow the typical layout of a PDP in my store.  I've tried changing content with custom templates but this requires a code change - is there any way to do this from the CMS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is entirely possible!

The easiest way to do this is to remove the content with **Custom Layout XML** and then replace that with the contents of a static block.

Layout XML:

```
<remove name="content">
<reference name="root">
    <block type="cms/block" name="my.custom.block" before="footer">
        <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>your_block_id</block_id></action>
    </block> 
</reference>
```